# R polygon vectors for points

Tags: r

I am trying to color in from the top of the graph (y=5) to the line that was in the original plot by creating a polygon and filling it in. I'm screwing up the point generation somehow. Can someone explain whats wrong here? (Didn't mean to fill in the triangle)

```
half_instances<-c(0,5,2)
Ts<-c(1,2,3)

xpairs<-c(Ts, rep(5,length(half_instances)))
ypairs<-c(Ts,half_instances)
xpairs #1 2 3 5 5 5
ypairs #0 5 2 1 2 3


plot(Ts,half_instances,type="l")
polygon(xpairs,ypairs)
```

[image]

accidental output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up your x and y values, the 5's need to go into the vector for the y coordinates:

```
half_instances<-c(0,5,2)
Ts<-c(1,2,3)

xpairs <- c(Ts, rev(Ts))
xpairs # 1 2 3 3 2 1 = original x-values from left to right for the bottom half, then go back from right to left by using the reverse of the original x-values
ypairs <- c(half_instances, rep(5, length(half_instances)))
ypairs # 0 5 2 5 5 5 = original y-values for bottom half, then fill up with 5's tor the top half

plot(Ts, half_instances,type="l")
polygon(xpairs, ypairs, col="red")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have points at coordinate X = 5, You need to modify xlim if you want to see the whole polygon:

```
half_instances<-c(0,5,2)
Ts<-c(1,2,3)

xpairs<-c(Ts, rep(5,length(half_instances)))
ypairs<-c(half_instances,Ts)
xpairs #1 2 3 5 5 5
ypairs #0 5 2 1 2 3


plot(Ts,half_instances,type="l",xlim=c(1,5))
polygon(xpairs,ypairs)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but hopefully the following code helps:

```
half_instances<-c(0,5,2)
Ts<-c(1,2,3)

xpairs<-c(Ts, rep(5,length(half_instances)))
ypairs<-c(Ts,half_instances)
xpairs #1 2 3 5 5 5
ypairs #0 5 2 1 2 3

points <- cbind(Ts, half_instances)

# Set up basic plot
plot(points, type="l")

# Create the outside polygon...
maxX <- max(points[, 1])
minX <- min(points[, 1])
maxY <- max(points[, 2])
minY <- min(points[, 2])

borderPoints <- matrix(c(minX,minY, minX,maxY, maxX,maxY), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
linePoints  <- points[nrow(points):1, ]
outside <- rbind(borderPoints, linePoints)

# ...and plot it in blue
polygon(outside, border=NA, col='blue')

# Create the inside polygon and plot it in red
inside <- rbind(points, pts[1,])
polygon(inside, col='red', border=NA)

# Redraw the initial line if you want
lines(points, col='black', lwd=2)
```

[image]